# Session is not configured. How to fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am starting to learn ASP.NET MVC. Now I'm trying to make authentication functionality without using [class Membership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership?view=netframework-3.5), [class FormsAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication?view=netframework-4.8), etc. I save the current username into session data.

To check if the user is authenticated I use the following code:

```cs
if (!HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains<string>("authentication")) { // It throws an exception
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

The first line of this snippet throws exception with the following message (my app shows message and target site):

> Session is not configured. At "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SessionState.HttpSessionState Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpContext.get_Session()".

## What I have tried:

1. Adding this line to my `Startup.cs`:

```cs
app.UseSession();
```

2. Calling `app.UseMvc()` in `Startup.cs` isn't required. But I tried using it (just calling `app.UseMvc()` throws an exception. I found the line below in an answer on Stack Overflow after some research):

```cs
app.UseMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

3. Using `Session.Keys.Contains<string>()` instead of `HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains<string>()`. But it didn't find a property named `Session`.
4. Surfing the Internet. I didn't find any good answers.
5. Now I asked my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved now. I have added these snippets to `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
services.AddSession();
```

and

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession();
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```